# How to set image under other image?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

How to set image under other image. There are two pictures user's photo and semi transparent picture which need to set over user's photo. How to do it with ExtJs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way.

```
Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
  src: 'http://www.sencha.com/img/20110215-feat-html5.png',
  width: 184,
  height: 90,
  autoEl: {
    tag: 'div'
  },
  id: 'image1',
  renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
  src: 'http://orig01.deviantart.net/2890/f/2012/168/0/a/labyrinth_free_background_transparent_png_by_jacobmainland-d53tglc.png',
  width: 184,
  height: 90,
  style: 'position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;',
  renderTo: Ext.get('image1')
});
```

[Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/vsr)

EDIT:

```
tbar: [{
  xtype: 'image',
  src: 'http://www.sencha.com/img/20110215-feat-html5.png',
  width: 184,
  height: 90,
  autoEl: {
    tag: 'div'
  },
  id: 'abc',
  listeners: {
    render: function() {
      Ext.create('Ext.Img', {
        src: 'http://orig01.deviantart.net/2890/f/2012/168/0/a/labyrinth_free_background_transparent_png_by_jacobmainland-d53tglc.png',
        width: 184,
        height: 90,
        style: 'position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;',
        renderTo: Ext.get('abc')
      });
    }
  }
}],
```

Comment: in this scope it work. But insert it in 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar' element is a more complicated task

Comment: I don't think so.  Updated the answer and fiddle.